# Recurrence relation of second order with polynomial coefficient

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, recurrence-relations

I have this recurrence relation of second order with polynomial coefficients:

$$(A^2n(n+2v))c_{ v}[n]=c_{v}[n-2]-(2n-2+2v)(2n-1+2v)c_{v}[n-1],$$ and the analogue replacing v with -v, with

- A and v real parameters (in particular $A>0$, $0<v<0.5$)
- $c_{v}[-2]=c_{v}[-1]=0$ and $c_{v}[0]=c0(v)$ arbitrary constant.

Could anyone please suggests me a way to find a solution for the generic term in closed form?

This recurrence comes from trying to solve the following differential equation
$$ \left[(A^2+4y)\frac{d^2}{d\,y^2}+2\frac{d}{d\,y}+\frac{(1/4-v^2)A^2}{y^2}-1\right]\phi(y)=0,$$
by power series:

$\phi_{v}(y)=y^{1/2+v}\Sigma_{n=0}^{n=\infty}c_{v}[n]y^n$.

Actually what I interested in is to construct a solution (similar to what happens for BesselK function):

$$\phi(y)=\phi_{v}(y)-\phi_{-v}(y)$$

decaying at +infinity so that it would be sufficienct to have a condition on the initial parameters $c0(v)$ and $c0(-v)$ to ensure the decaying, maybe studying some limit of the recurrence.

Thanks a lot for any suggestion