# Differential equation in one dimension (Second derivative+potential)

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

does anyone have any suggestion to solve this differential equation:

$$-f''(x)-\alpha^2\Big(\frac1x-\frac{1}{x+d}\Big)^2f(x)=-L^2f(x),$$
for $x>0$, where $0<\alpha<\frac12$ and $d>0$ are parameters and $-L^2$ a negative eigenvalue.

I know the solution in two limit:

1. when $d\rightarrow\infty$: $f(x)=x^{1/2}K_{v}(Lx)$, with $v=\sqrt{1/4-\alpha^2}$ and K is Bessel K
2. when $L=0$: $f(x)=x^{1/2+v}(x+d)^{1/2-v}- x^{1/2-v}(x+d)^{1/2+v}$

I would like to find the solution for generic d. I tried for example with a change of coordinate and  expanding in series, as explained here:
[Recurrence relation of second order with polynomial coefficient](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4155005/recurrence-relation-of-second-order-with-polynomial-coefficient) but I always get stucked.

Thanks for any kind of suggestion

Alessandro

Comment: Is that $=0$ needed at the end of the equation? Isn't the equality between the left-hand side and $-L^2 f(x)$?

Comment: It was an error, I have corrected

Comment: If the equation is $$
f''(x) + \left( {-L^2  + \alpha \left( {\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{{x + d}}} \right)^2 } \right)f(x) = 0
$$  and $d$ is finite, the asymptotics can be obtained by http://dlmf.nist.gov/2.7.ii See http://dlmf.nist.gov/2.7.i for the notation ($f$ and $g$).

Comment: The method in the reference works if $L\neq 0$.