# Asymptotic expansions (large argument) for Bessel K function

Tags: complex-analysis

The $K$ Bessel function is defined as (let's assume $x$ is real):
$$
K_{\nu}=\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{I_{-\nu}(x)-I_{\nu}(x)}{\sin(\nu\pi)},
$$
where
$$
I_{\nu}(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!\Gamma(1+n+\nu)}\Big(\frac{x}{2}\Big)^{2n+\nu}.
$$

I would to know how it is possible to deduce the asymptotic expansions  for large $x$:
$$
I_{\nu}(x)\sim \frac{e^x}{\sqrt{2\pi x}}\Big(1-\frac{4\nu^2-1}{8x}+\frac{(4\nu^2-1)(4\nu^2-9)}{2!(8x)^2}+\ldots\Big)
$$
and
$$
K_{\nu}(x)\sim \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2x}}e^{-x}\Big(1+\frac{4\nu^2-1}{8x}+\frac{(4\nu^2-1)(4\nu^2-9)}{2!(8x)^2}+\ldots\Big).
$$

Answer (score 3):

You can establish them by applying [Watson's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watson%27s_lemma) to the integral representations
$$
I_\nu  (z) = \frac{1}{{\sqrt \pi  \Gamma\! \left( {\nu  + \frac{1}{2}} \right)}}(2z)^\nu  \mathrm{e}^z \int_0^1 {\mathrm{e}^{ - 2zt} t^{\nu  - 1/2} (1 - t)^{\nu  - 1/2} \mathrm{d}t} 
$$
and
$$
K_\nu  (z) = \frac{{\sqrt \pi  }}{{\Gamma\! \left( {\nu  + \frac{1}{2}} \right)}}\left( {\frac{2}{z}} \right)^\nu  \mathrm{e}^{ - z} \int_0^{ + \infty } {\mathrm{e}^{ - 2zt} t^{\nu  - 1/2} (1 + t)^{\nu  - 1/2} \mathrm{d}t} ,
$$
where $\operatorname{Re}(z)>0$ and $\operatorname{Re}(\nu) >- \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Hi, thanks. What I am interested is to undestand better the following point: the power series for Bessel I(v) is defined in principle with an arbitrary constant c0 (the first term), that is choosen to be 1/Gamma[1+v] so that the Bessel K function constructed as difference of I(v) and I(-v) decays at infinity. What I am interested is to know if there is the possibility to deduce the behaviour at infinity starting from the power expansion in x,x^2,... so that to obtain a kind of constrain to determine the initial constant. The theorem you mention looks to be related to integral representation.

Comment: I am asking this because I am studying a similar problem that is explained here [link]( https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4157874/differential-equation-in-one-dimension-second-derivativepotential), and the Bessel K function is like a case study of this more difficult problem. Thanks again

Comment: Gary, nice answer. The Wikipedia page mentions only integrals over finite regions $(0,T)$. Can we extend it as $T\to \infty$ as would be required for the integral representation for Bessel K?

Comment: @K.defaoite Yes, you have to show that the tail is exponentially small, so it can be absorbed into the error term (dacays faster than any negative power of the large variable). See https://dlmf.nist.gov/2.3#ii

Comment: @AlessandroSantagata Then this seems to be an XY problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem

Comment: Do you, by chance, know a good expansion of $J_n(x)$ for large $n$ and $x \sim n$ ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici How about http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.19.E8 ? If $|x-n| =o(n^{1/3})$, I know an even simpler one, see $(1.3)$ here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1407.5299.pdf